# How to use VS debugger to inspect a C++ exception object during the "first-chance"?

Tags: c++, debugging, exception, com, visual-studio-debugging

My program calls into a library for which I don't have source code (Direct2D [`ID2D1DCRenderTarget::BeginDraw`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371768(v=vs.85).aspx)).  Visual Studio debugger gives me a "first-chance" when that library code throws an exception.  I have the definition of the thrown object (it's a [`_com_error`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ye3k36s.aspx)).  **How can I inspect that object in the debugger at that point?**

I tried modifying my code to catch the exception, but the library is catching (and handling?) the exception before it propagates back to the call site.  I tried poking around at the registers and memory in the debugger at the point of the first-chance exception, but I don't know enough about how VS maps exceptions into the ABI to really know where to look.  Is there a particular register that points to the exception object?

Why I'm asking:  I'm trying to figure out if this exception is part of the normal operation of the library or if it's indicative of a bug in how I'm using the library.  The library appears to be handling whatever exceptional condition arises, but I'm not sure if it's just covering up a mistake on my part.  In certain circumstances[*], it happens in every iteration of a hot loop[**], so I'm concerned about the performance impact of the exception propagation.  I'm hoping the details in the `_com_error` exception object will give me a clue as to what's going on under the covers.

[*] The certain circumstances are that a high-contrast theme is selected.  When a "standard" theme is selected, no exception is thrown.

[**] It's a hot loop because it's every frame of an animation.  And, actually, it's a few times per frame because I'm animating on a few render targets simultaneously and the exception happens on the BeginDraw call for every target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The address listed in the throw should be the address of a _com_error object. If he turns on the Microsoft Symbol Server, you should be able to inspect the properties of the _com_error and the IErrorInfo it’s holding internally.

Example:

Exception thrown at 0x757708F2 in ConsoleApplication1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x00BAFA70.

Watch window:

[image]

However, I would suggest you turn on the sdk layers instead:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee794277(v=vs.85).aspx

That should tell you if anything is going wrong with his D2D calls better than inspecting an error that may be intentional.

Comment: Thanks!  Sadly, the _com_error didn't give any useful detail beyond `E_FAIL`.  I didn't know about the debug level, so I enabled that but didn't get any useful information there either.  So I guess these exceptions are "normal" for a high-contrast theme.

Comment: Thank for this answer. This works nicely for any of the thrown exceptions. I just did it with `std::ios_base::failure` and I can drill down into `std::exception` and view the `_What` member text that `std::exception::what()` would have returned. All without having to write the code to catch the exception first. I wonder why there isn't a link to click that would add the exception to the watch window? This is so useful and wasn't obvious to me that I could just provide the debugger with the address and object type to view it. In hindsight, it should have been obvious. :)